# getElementsByClassName returning undefined in javascript want to delete list item when user click on delete icon

Tags: javascript, html-lists, listitem, getelementsbyclassname

This function not deleting list item when I click on delete icon..its returning this error
main.js:108 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined
    at HTMLImageElement.

Here is the code

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var abbrs =  document.querySelectorAll(".imageicon");
for( var i=0; i< abbrs.length; i++) {
    abbrs[i].addEventListener('click',function() {
        var ist = list.abbrs[i];
        list.removeChild(ist);
     })
    }
```

Comment: use `for (let i = 0 ....` - because by the time the event handler is called, `i === abbrs.length` if you use `var` ... also `list.abbrs` won't be a thing ... as the variable `list` is an element, and elements do not have a property called `abbrs`

Comment: also, your question doesn't use `getElementsByClassName` - so the title of the question is completely misleading

Comment: for( let i=0; i< abbrs.length; i++) 
it still gives error

Comment: i tried both functions query select and getElementsByClass stil the same result

Comment: yes, because your code still suffers the problems I mentioned in the first comment

Comment: * it still gives error* - what error? that `list.abbrs` is undefined - because it is ... use `abbrs[i]` instead ... you've declared `list` and `abbrs` as variables ... that doesn't magically create `list.abbrs`

Comment: can you please provide me a code that can solve my problem i am a beginner and not understanding what you are saying

Comment: what I've said so far is 1: use `let i` ... and 2: change `var ist = list.abbrs[i];` to `var ist = abbrs[i];` - I won't be adding an answer